# jumping problem in react native when adding items to the front

Tags: react-native, flatlist

<FlatList
data={messages}
inverted
onEndReached={loadMoreOlderMessages}

```
    onStartReached={loadMoreRecentMessages}
   
    renderItem={MessageBubble}
    horizontal
    onStartReachedThreshold={20} // optional
    onEndReachedThreshold={15} // optional
    bounces = {true}
    disableVirtualization={true}
    
    
  />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you manipulate `messages` directly instead of recreating data array.

I expect somewhere in your code is something like:

```
messages.push(message)
```

You should change this to:

```
const newMessages = […messages, message];
```